# Is there a way to find out if current Netsuite record is a subrecord of another record inside suitescript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

The problem:
I'm working on client script (pageInit entry) for Inventory Detail record (id: inventorydetail), but I need this script to run **ONLY** when this record (inventorydetail) is being loaded from Item Receipt record (not Item Fulfillment or any other).

Is there a way to get '*super*' record type during script execution or can I specify this logic (run for inventory detail in context of item receipt only) in Ntesuite UI?

**Note:** 
Script will have to change (or at least set default) values inside inventory detail form before any user changes or, ideally, it should catch user changes and perform some actions. SuiteScript2.0 preferably.

Comment: Do you want to set these default values when the user views the inventory detail or only when they edit the detail?

Comment: I want to set default values during user edit/create event, and it's not a problem for me with NS API, but I'd like to apply this behaviour for inventorydetail, which was created/edited inside the itemreceipt only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if NetSuite has an API for it. Will have to check. But if there is no NetSuite API we can achieve it through JavaScript DOM. You can use `window.parent.location.path` in which you will get the reference off from which record the subrecord has been opened.

Comment: Thanks! 
I'm using window.parent.location.pathname and check if parent pathname has 'itemrcpt' inside. Though I'm not happy with using window functionality here.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to make use of a user event script.

Inventory Detail is not considered a record on NetSuite and you can therefore not apply a user event script to it. It is a subrecord and you can think of it as a field with multiple attributes.

You might have to apply your script as a user event script to the Item Receipt record. Your script will have to update the inventory detail on the "BEFORE LOAD FUNCTION" user event. This would mean that the default values will be populated on the inventory detail, but will not be saved to the database until the user saves the Item Receipt record.

In SuiteScript 2, get the inventory detail subrecord for each line on your ItemReceipt and change the values as you wish:

```
var inventoryDetailRecord = itemReceipt.getSublistSubrecord({
      sublistId: 'item',
      fieldId: 'inventorydetail',
      line: i
    });

    inventoryDetailRecord.setSublistValue({
      sublistId: 'inventoryassignment',
      fieldId: 'issueinventorynumber',
      value: serialId,
      line: 0
    });
```

The downside to this solution is that you'll be populating data on a subrecord, even if the subrecord is not viewed - this might not be ideal, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for reply, for me this is crucial to be able to get parent record in the client script attached to inventorydetail record (not sure why you're saying that it's restricted, it is obviously a valid case).

Comment: Have you tried Purna's solution? His answer might be the answer you need. Please see my correction above, "User Event Scripts" can't be applied to subrecords. Why do you specifically need to use a client script?

Comment: I didn't have a chance to test Purna's solution. I will try it asap, feels like that is exactly what I need. I need to implement my logic in client script, ideally, because it should respond to user input. User event script is a fallback solution for my task, trying to avoid that. Anyway thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SS 1.0 command on the script attached to the Inventory Detail making reference to the parent (window):

```
parent.nlapiGetRecordType()
```